# Google Compute Engine: Load balacing(cross-region) only when health-check fails

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example) using "Cross Region load balancing" requests are routed to the closest region automatically.

Is there any way to disable this? I would like to switch over other region only when the health-check fails.

Comment: No, Google load balancer automatically routes to closest healthiest instance. Why do you want to impose prioritization other than "closest"? If the two backends are identical, wouldn't you want the closest server to the user handle the request (to minimize user-visible latency)? If they're not identical, how will you handle failover when your primary server is unhealthy?

Comment: Our system is quite complex, having two active zones would mean having a rabbitmq cluster, a mysql cluster, and the same for other components. We don't want to overcomplicate our infrastructure as we don't have any problems handling our load, we can take care of it with just one zone.

The reason we want two zones is to be more reliable and switch over to the other when a problem is detected through health checks.

Comment: Are you not running the same stack in two places (zones or regions)? If yes, you should be able to load-balance requests. If not, and your app only works in a single zone, and the second one is incomplete or missing, how will you failover to a second zone instantly when the load balancer starts sending requests to it automatically?

Comment: You could setup Backend Services for both the Regions. In the Backend Service that you want to be failover, modify the "maximum utilization" to 5%. This should make this Region serve very low traffic, yet be active.